# Create a new String Array from class array

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have a class called `Person`:

```
class Person {

    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?
    let birthPlace = "Belgium"

}


let person = [Person]()
```

Now the problem is I want to get all first names into a `String` array (`[String]`), how can I do it?

Comment: Why are `firstName` and `lastName` optional? In practice everybody has a first and last name. Don't use optionals as an alibi not to write an initializer. That's very bad habit.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flatMap` for that:

```
let firstName = person.flatMap{ return $0.firstName }
```

Comment: Why `flatMap`? The array is not nested in any way.

Comment: `flatMap` will create an array of non-optional strings `[String]`, that's what OP asked for. The `firstName` property is an optional (`String?`), so the result of `map{ return $0.firstName}` will be `[String?]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should rewrite your `Person` class. `firstName` and `lastName` shouldn't be optional, since everyone has both a first and a last name and unless your app will specifically be made for people who were born in Belgium, hardcoding that as the `birthPlace` is also a bad idea.

Take the time and write an initializer for the class.

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    let birthPlace: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, birthPlace: String){
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.birthPlace = birthPlace
    }
}
```

You can use `map` to get an array of first names from an array of `Person` objects.

```
let people = [Person]()
let firstNames = people.map{$0.firstName}
```